# What is a helper in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to find information on the web and could not know exactly what a helper was and what it was used for. if someone could answer me. I found this example on the web:

```
// controller.js
callServer: function(cmp, helper) {
  helper.callServer();
}
 
//helper.js ()
callServer: function(cmp, helper) {
   var action = cmp.get("c.getAccounts");
   $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: Do have some more context, such as where on the web you found that example? There's nothing in node.js called a generic "helper" so it's hard to tell from the question.

Comment: I attach some videos that talk about the subject -youtube.com/watch?v=k5mYz-yYtKM - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8CxcV81Shw&t=296s

Comment: Looks like a bad attempt at dependency injection paired with bad naming.

Comment: The first video is just showing writing functions to do useful things - "helpers". I have no idea what the second video is supposed to be demonstrating.